# Norm of derivative and contractive function

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, contraction-mapping

It is a widely know fact (at least for me, I might be wrong) that, given a function $f(x)$, the condition $|f'(x)| < 1$ is enough to see that the function is contractive. However, the problem becomes harder when it comes to several variables. I know that, if we consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, if $||Df(x)||_2 < 1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then this function is contractive (here, $||Df(x)||$ means the 2-norm operator of the jacobian matrix at that point).

In many contexts, given the expression, it seems way easier using operator norms like $||\cdot||_1$ or $||\cdot||_{\infty}$. I was wondering if the bounding of the norm of the derivative by $1$ is enough condition for contractiveness for any norm $p$, or $p=2$ is the only case. I know that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ all $p$-norms are equivalent.

Besides and since one can consider the operator norm of non-square matrix, is the same result valid in this case?

Comment: If you do it for any p-norm with $p\leq 2$, you're good, as that implies the same bound for the 2-norm (by monotonicity of $\ell_p$ norms).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: On the real line $\|x||=\frac 1 2|x|$ is also a norm. The condition $\|f'(x)\|=\frac 1  2|f'(x)|<1$ does not gaurantee that $f$ is a contraction for this  norm. Can you find a counter-example?

Comment: I think I can find it. However, isn't there any related result? I knew something similar to the fact that $|f'(x)| < 1 \Rightarrow f $ contractive. Is there any additional condition?

Comment: $\|Df(x)\|<1$ some norm says almost nothing. It cannot make $f$ contractive.

Comment: Isn't there any related result? I am currently watching an exercise I was given and in the solution the use that for $p=2$.